# Move values to the row of the first value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I've been working with Python for a short time and I usually find the answers in the web when I have a problem, but I don't find something similar and I feel stuck, so I am going to explain my problem.

In a simplified way, I have a dataframe like this:

`df`:

| ID | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 0 |

I want to move all the '1s' from the `X`, `Y` and `Z` columns to the row with the first value of their respective `ID` column.

This would be the desired output:

`end_df`:

| ID | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I have thought that I could move the values and then delete all the remaining rows with
`df.groupby('ID').first()`, but I don't know how I could move the values up to their respective rows.

Comment: There is only `0, 1`, so possible use `df.groupby('ID').max()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean by?

```
>>> df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).max()
  ID  X  Y  Z
0  A  1  0  1
1  B  1  1  1
>>>
```